# How to handle __stack_chk_guard in LLVM assembly code

Tags: llvm, mips, llvm-clang

I compile a C program to MIPS assembly code. And i notice there's a __stack_chk_guard symbol.

I need to write an assembler for the assembly code. But i don't know how to handle this symbol. I searched all Google but found nothing. Right now i need to disable stack protector using :

```
clang -fno-stack-protector
```

I guess it's not a good idea though. So can anyone help to explain this to me ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Handle it in what way?